# On the AP/Google election tracker, are 'Electoral Votes' describing Electoral College votes?

Tags: united-states, election, voting

As someone outside of the US, I'm finding it a little hard to interpret the results from the current election tracker widget that google is using to display the election results.

When the graph is showing 'Electoral Votes', is this describing the 'Electoral College Votes' that ultimately decides the winning presidential candidate?

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: @gerrit only a google search link sorry:  
https://www.google.com/search?q=us+election+tracker&rlz=1C1GCEB_enAU918AU918&oq=us&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j69i57j0i67i131i433i457j0i67i131i433j69i60l2.894j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: Electoral Votes is another way of saying votes in the [Electoral College](https://www.ncsl.org/research/elections-and-campaigns/the-electoral-college.aspx).  The Electoral College is the collection of people who select the next President; an Electoral Vote refers to the actual vote they hold (and then, cast).  A state is referred to as having so many Electoral Votes, generally, with the word "college" omitted.